# Safety of running cron job on first day of every month

Tags: mysql, sql, cron

Would it be unwise to create a cron job that runs once every month, at the beginning of each month, to enter several thousand new rows into an SQL table?

My thinking is that, what if something unexpected happens, like the server goes offline at the very time the cron is supposed to execute, or some other unexpected event.

Would it be better to maybe have the cron run once *every day* just to check that the rows exist in the table? If not, it would add them?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is like month end or month begging processing, there is no risk it it, you have to assume there will be issues, which is why you probably want to implement some alerting feature that would let you know the run was successful, or if unsuccessful, what the error was.

The only risk would be is that you get your code right, Quality Assure test it, but in general no, automated jobs to do data processing are done all of the time.

Re-reading your question:

> Would it be better to maybe have the cron run once every day just to
>   check that the rows exist in the table? If not, it would add them?

How about a trigger? Then it would be done immediately.

Happy to help more if you explain the use case in more detail.